# Box-Shadow over angled corner

Tags: html, css

I have an element with a slanted bottom-right corner, over which I have to lay a box-shadow. Sometimes the slanted corner is covered up by a badge - my problem does not apply, if that is the case:

[image]

This is the (s)css part for the infobox and its corners (there are some more styles, but they're just text modifiers... The whole thing is on codepen: https://codepen.io/kerowan/pen/bqMOeB

```
.product-info-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  .product-info {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1rem * .5;
    padding-right: 1rem * 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      background-color: lighten(#000, 93.5%);
      border-color: lighten(#000, 93.5%);
    }
    &:before {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 35px;
    }
    &:after {
      top: auto;
      right: -5px;
      bottom: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 35px 35px 0 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-right-color: transparent;
    }
  }
}
```

How can this be done (moving the shadow along the slanted corner)? Can it be done, if the slanted corners are generated the way I do it? I'm kind of dependant on those classes (I think at least) because of all the `relative` and `absolute` positioning, which I needed to place the corner badge.

**EDIT**: some HTML, if you need it:

```
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="product-info-wrapper">
          <div class="product-info">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-8">
                <strong class="text-uppercase">Amino Force</strong>
                <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 text-right">
                <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="product-info-wrapper">
          <div class="product-info">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-8">
                <strong class="text-uppercase">Amino Force</strong>
                <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 text-right">
                <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product-badge-wrapper">
            <div class="product-badge red">
              <div class="product-badge-content">
                new
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is just part of the whole HTML code which can be found on the codepen thingy. But I guessed, that this would be the only relevant part. If you need more, please tell me!

**EDIT2**

The contents of this infobox can be expanded. If I click on "Kurzinfo", it expands and shows more info. That's not on the codepen version, as I created it way before I added the expansion functionality.

Comment: You could use an image for the background of the box, and make the image in Paint.NET - include a drop shadow in the image

Comment: @AnishGoyal The contents of this `product-info` thingy have to be flexible, as it expands, when I click on "Kurzinfo"... gonna add it to the question. I feel like using a background image wouldn't work for this case

Comment: What if you made an absolutely positioned (give your box relative positioning) an equivalent box, but black, with z-index -1, to serve as a pseudo shadow? You'd lose spread, but I don't think CSS won't  let you do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normally impossible, because the slanted corner is a part of border of element that is not visible.

[image]

In image if the blue area changes to white you have a slanted corner black area, that is a part of border and in css we can not any think to change this.(change as you want).

You can cover the shadows by adding two little divs to the product div:

```
<div class="product-info-wrapper">
    <div class="coverShadow c1"></div>
    <div class="coverShadow c2"></div>
    ....
```

And CSS:

```
.coverShadow {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   background-color: white;
   box-shadow: 0 0 14px white;
 }

 .coverShadow.c1 {
    width: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: -10px;
 }

 .coverShadow.c2 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0;
 }
```

By changing the **box shadow** and **width/height** and **right/bottom** of covering divs it could be more smooth.

And thanks for the good idea for creating slanted corners.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well, it's a pity that this doesn't seem to going to work... Do you know if it would be possible if I created the slant differently? I think there's a way with gradients... I don't know how this would affect the overall outcome, because as I said, I'm pretty dependant on the `relative` and `absolute` positioning of those elements

Comment: Please see my updated answer, It will help to better understanding what i mean. And it has not any problem with responsive and absolute positioning. because covering divs are related to product div and where it is, they are there and in right bottom corner of that. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: *Do you know if it would be possible if I created the slant differently? I think there's a way with gradients* ... I think it is impossible, The box shadow is for the product div and there is not any related with this and a piece of border of child element, that is not visible (slanted corner).

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 you could get rid of the elements and styles `.coverShadow`, `.coverShadow.c1` and `coverShadow.c2` suggested by @Farzin's answer. Instead, for the `.product-info` element replace

`box-shadow: 0 5px 5px`

with

`filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px #333)`

(blur amount and color might need to be adjusted).

The [drop-shadow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()) will adapt to any shape, not just rectangles. It will also work in [most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=drop-shadow).